# Font-awesome icons, change color in the middle of the icon (the text)

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have a problem, changing the text color of my font-awesome social icons. Right now it's transparent which looks weird because of my footer background-color. Is there any way that I can change it to white?

Have tried with color: (and a color code) but that only changes the color around the text.

It looks like this:

**My html code:**

```
<div class="social-content">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x fb-btn"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x twit-btn"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square fa-3x you-btn"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-3x gog-btn"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-3x ins-btn"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square fa-3x pen-btn"></i></a>
</div>
```

**My css code:**

```
.fb-btn {
    color: #2D609B;
}

.twit-btn {
    color: #00C3F3;    
}

.you-btn {
    color: #CC181E;    
}

.gog-btn {
    color: #F6861F;
}

.ins-btn {
    color: #517FA6;    
}

.pen-btn {
    color: #CC1D1F;    
}
```

Not sure if i'm using the right icons etc fa-facebook-square and if it locked to be transparent.

Comment: Try changing background.color

Comment: Already tried.. the background filled more than the icon

Comment: change the `background-color` of the `<a>`, add padding to it and then change the `color` of the `<i>`

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a white background. You can achieve this with a Font Awesome icon stack. To do this, use a `fa-square` and make the `color: white;` and put this underneath the square social media icon.

**HTML**

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-2x social social-fb">
    <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-1x white-bg"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-stack-2x "></i>                    
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Just to create some contrast */
body {
    background: #DA4A10;  
    margin: 10px;      
}

/* Color of the social media icon */
.social-fb { color: #2D609B; }

/* Definition of the white background */
.white-bg {
    color: white;
    font-size: 54px;
}
```

Check my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/11326/) to see the code in action.