# Font-Awesome Icons, Change Color In The Middle of The Icon (The Text) On Hover

Tags: html, css

This question is pretty similar to [one that's already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120902/font-awesome-icons-change-color-in-the-middle-of-the-icon-the-text), except that I'm trying to change the text-color of the icon only when you hover over it.

Right now, hovering over the icons looks like this:

[image]

Although the color is correct, you can see that it's extending outside of the icon. Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="social-media-container">
    <li class="social-media">
        <a class="fa fa-facebook-square"
                       href="https://www.facebook.com/gatewaywebdesign18/?ref=aymt_homepage_panel"
                       target="blank"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="social-media">
        <a class="fa fa-twitter-square"
                       href="https://www.twitter.com/gatewaywebdesign18/?ref=aymt_homepage_panel"
                       target="blank"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="social-media">
        <a class="fa fa-linkedin-square"
                       href="https://www.linkedin.com/gatewaywebdesign18/?ref=aymt_homepage_panel"
                       target="blank"></a>
     </li>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#social-media-container {
position: relative;
float: right;
margin-top: 10px;
}

.social-media a {
color: #ffffff;
display: table-cell;
font-size: 25px;
padding: 0px;
}

.social-media a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
background-color: #1971b9;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I've tried to adjust the border radius on `.social-media a:hover` but it's still extending past the icon:

[image]

I've also tried to adjust the padding of `.social-media a:hover`, but no effect. This website is live here: http://nowordpress.gatewaywebdesign.com/. I tried to create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7yjsLja/) but it looks like it won't load the external resource (font-awesome.min.css). Any suggestions? Thanks.

**EDIT**: Link to working [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/2034/) with loaded font-awesome stylesheet.

Comment: can you update your fiddle taking this example please? http://jsfiddle.net/leolanese/JfGVE/ This has the font awesome css.

Comment: of course, please see the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is also solvable by using Font Awesome's stack system, just like in the link you mentioned:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/gatewaywebdesign18/?ref=aymt_homepage_panel" target="blank">
  <span class="fa-stack icon-facebook">
    <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-1x outside"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x inside"></i>
  </span>
</a>
```

And the CSS:

```
.social-media a .fa-stack {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.social-media a .outside {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.social-media a .inside {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #1B3764;
}

.social-media a:hover .inside {
  color: #1971b9;
}
```

```css
#social-media-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #1B3764;
}

.social-media a {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.social-media a .fa-stack {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.social-media a .outside {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.social-media a .inside {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #1B3764;
}

.social-media a:hover .inside {
  color: #1971b9;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="social-media-container">
  <li class="social-media">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/gatewaywebdesign18/?ref=aymt_homepage_panel" target="blank">
      <span class="fa-stack icon-facebook">
        <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-1x outside"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x inside"></i>
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="social-media">
    <a href="https://www.twitter.com/gatewaywebdesign18/?ref=aymt_homepage_panel" target="blank">
      <span class="fa-stack icon-twitter">
        <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-1x outside"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x inside"></i>
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="social-media">
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/gatewaywebdesign18/?ref=aymt_homepage_panel" target="blank">
      <span class="fa-stack icon-linkedin">
        <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-1x outside"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-stack-1x inside"></i>
      </span>
    </a>
   </li>
</div>
```

This will change only the **inner** color.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="fa fa-facebook-square" href="https://www.facebook.com/gatewaywebdesign18/?ref=aymt_homepage_panel" target="blank"></a>
```

to

```
<a class="" href="https://www.facebook.com/gatewaywebdesign18/?ref=aymt_homepage_panel" target="blank">
  <i class="fa fa-facebook-square" style="
    color: #337ab7;
"></i>
</a>
```

And you can give the < a > tag's background color to transparent.
After that, you can give < i > tags color as your reqeust.

```
.social-media a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
background-color: #1971b9;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

to

```
.social-media a i:hover {
text-decoration:none;
background-color: #1971b9;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: And you can give the <a> tag's background color to transparent. After that, you can give <i> tags color as your reqeust.

Comment: Sorry but unless I'm missing something, this seems to be doing the same thing:     

http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/2042/

Comment: do you want to view in jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi I checked your js fiddle.you should remove background color of <i> tag.And you should remove color:white of a tag.

Comment: <a class="social-media-icon" href="https://www.facebook.com/gatewaywebdesign18/?ref=aymt_homepage_panel" target="blank">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook-square" style="color: white;"></i>
      </a>

Comment: to                          <a class="social-media-icon" href="https://www.facebook.com/gatewaywebdesign18/?ref=aymt_homepage_panel" target="blank">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
      </a>

Comment: .social-media a i:hover {
text-decoration:none;
background-color: #337ab7;
border-radius: 5px;
}

Comment: to .social-media a i:hover {
text-decoration:none;
color: #337ab7;
border-radius: 5px;
}

Comment: And you cannot set the letter "f" 's color. this is my skype id. arnoldbenda

Answer (score 1):

or you can use this

```
            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
              <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x"></i>
            </span>
```

you can modify the icon size by modifying font size.

Comment: This solution is simpler and more effective IMO - thanks!